# Is there another method for solving $y''+\frac{1}{x}y'+\frac{1}{x^2}y=0$ beside the Frobenius method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there another method for solving $y''+\frac{1}{x}y'+\frac{1}{x^2}y=0$ where c is a constant beside the Frobenius method?

I have forgotten some of the moethods to solve ode's. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

This is a Euler-Cauchy equation, so multiply by $x^2$ and substitute $y(x) = x^m$ with $y, y', y''$ and solve for the $m's$.

What do you mean by $c$?

Comment: I had it wrong initially, and for c I meant $3+\lambda$. The one I have is $y''+\frac{1}{x}y'+\frac{3+\lambda}{x^2}y=0$

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'll try to solve it!!

Comment: The hint still works for that $c$.

Answer (score 0):

The original equation is homogeneous, so can be solved with the substitution  x = exp(-t).

If I have done it right, this reduces it to

y^^ + cy = 0 ,   which is standard, and easy to solve.

(where ^ is differentiation with respect to  t).

Bill Taylor.